# Sorting list of lists by a third list of specified non-sorted order

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list:

```
[['18411971', 'kinase_2', 36], ['75910712', 'unnamed...', 160], ...
```

- about 60 entries long
- each entry is a list with three values

I want to sort this bigger list by the first value in an order specified by another list which has them in the desired order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual idiom is to sort using a key:

```
>>> a = [[1,2],[2,10,10],[3,4,'fred']]
>>> b = [2,1,3]
>>> sorted(a,key=lambda x: b.index(x[0]))
[[2, 10, 10], [1, 2], [3, 4, 'fred']]
```

This can have performance issues, though-- if the keys are hashable, this will probably be faster for long lists:

```
>>> order_dict = dict(zip(b, range(len(b))))
>>> sorted(a,key=lambda x: order_dict[x[0]])
[[2, 10, 10], [1, 2], [3, 4, 'fred']]
```

Comment: That would be a nice place for function composition: `key = b.index . itemgetter(0)` :) Unfortunately Python doesn't have it built-in :(

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
inputlist = [['18411971', 'kinase_2', 36], ['75910712', 'unnamed...', 160], ... # obviously not valid syntax
auxinput = aux = ['75910712', '18411971', ...] # ditto
keyed = { sublist[0]:sublist for sublist in inputlist }
result = [keyed[item] for item in auxinput]
```

There is no need to use sorting here. For large lists this would be faster, because it's `O(n)` rather than `O(n * log n)`.

In case the keys aren't unique, it is possible to use some variant of an ordered dict (e.g. `defaultdict(list)` as per Niklas B's suggestion) to build the keyed representation.

Comment: This assumes that the first entries are unique, but that could very well be the case.  +1.

Comment: +1, while this is more verbose than sorting with `auxinput.index` as the key, it's about the same amount of code than the dict-based sorting. If the entries weren't unique, one could use a `defaultdict` to build a `key->[values]` association and then use `[keyed[x] for item in auxinput for x in item]`, which would still be `O(n)` if the number of duplicates is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand you right, you have your sample input list:

```
a = [['18411971', 'kinase_2', 36], ['75910712', 'unnamed...', 160], ...
```

and you want to sort this using an extra list that mentions the order in which the first elements of the sub-lists are to occur in the output:

```
aux = ['75910712', '18411971', ...]
```

If that's right, I think the result can be achieved using something like:

```
sorted(a, key = lambda x: aux.index(x[0]))
```