# Python, sort a list of dicts by an arbitrary order

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting list of lists by a third list of specified non-sorted order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994317/sorting-list-of-lists-by-a-third-list-of-specified-non-sorted-order)

```
a = [{'id':1}, {'id':2}, {'id':3}]
b = [2,1,3]
```

What would be a good method to sort `dict` a by `list` b via the `id` property.

The result should look something like this

```
[{'id':2}, {'id':1}, {'id':3}]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No voodoo is required, as long as you can guarantee `b` has been populated with all the `id`s in `a`:

```
In [1]: a = [{'id':1}, {'id':2}, {'id':3}]

In [2]: b = [2,1,3]

In [3]: a.sort(key=lambda v : b.index(v['id']))

In [4]: a
Out[4]: [{'id': 2}, {'id': 1}, {'id': 3}]
```

(I'm often told there's an alternative to `lambda` that should be used nowadays, but this is still the clearest way I know for doing this)

**EDIT:**  Also note that this is nearly identical to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9994418/500202) in the linked question.

Comment: + 1: I agree: the key parameter is often forgot, and a lambda is often the clearest way of doing this.

Comment: Note that list.index does a linear search, so if len(b) is big this will be very slow.

Comment: in this case it shouldn't get very big, less then 100 items. But thank you for the note.

Comment: @NickCraig-Wood Ack, I didn't even think of that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
dictFromList = dict(zip((x['id'] for x in a), a))
sortedList = [dictFromList[i] for i in b]
```

Comment: @rubik just curious, could you expand on your PEP 8 comment?

Comment: the naming should be `dict_from_list` if it follows PEP8 not camel-case

Comment: @Levon: I was referring to variables names. http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: I am not sure if this was what he wanted...

Comment: Despite the name `id`, Matt did not indicate it is a unique value.  It may have just been used as an example.  This will clobber any duplicates, if they exist.

Comment: @Izkata: True. One could probably just zip the indexes of list `b` to the dicts in list `a` and sort by `key=lambda x: x[1]` or something similar

Answer (score 1):

Python 2.7:

```
def sort_dict_by_list(a, b):        
    sortkeys = { v: k for (k, v) in enumerate(b) }
    return list(sorted(a, key=lambda x: sortkeys[x['id']]))

a = [{ 'id': 1, 'name': 'foo' }, { 'id': 2, 'name': 'bar' }, { 'id': 3, 'name': 'baz' }]
b = [2,1,3]
print sort_dict_by_list(a, b)
```

prints:

```
[{'id': 2, 'name': 'bar'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'foo'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'baz'}]
```

Comment: Essentially the same as Izkata, it seems, but O(n) complexity for the keying instead of O(n^2)

Comment: The python docs imply that this is what the `key` parameter does internally